# Html5 Canvas - Javascript Rotate, translate

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Here is the code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.save();
//context.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 20);
  
// step 1
context.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
context.rotate(90 * Math.PI /180);
  
// step 2
context.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 20);
  
// step 3
context.translate(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2);
  
context.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 20);
    
// step 4
context.translate(50, 0);
  
context.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 20);
context.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

I would expect that the translate in step 3 would put back the 0, 0 at the top left corner but it doesn't.

```
// step 3
context.translate(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2);
```

Is there any formula to calculate the top left corner and add it to the translation of step 4 so that the rectangle becomes visible at 50 next to the top left corner?

```
// step 4
context.translate(50, 0);
```

Comment: To "untransform" you must reverse the original transformations in reverse order. So if you translate(x,y) + rotate(z) then you must untransform with rotate(-z) + translate(-x,-y). If you want to track how the canvas has been transformed you can use a transformation matrix. You can read about the transformation matrix in [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/5494/transformations/19666/a-transformation-matrix-to-track-translated-rotated-scaled-shapes#t=201609281547513705079).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to understand the transformation matrix. It seems to be what I need.